# Динамическая фильтрация объектов в зависимости от введенной последовательности букв

Tags: jquery, css

Исходное состояние страницы: поле ввода текста и под ним полный список городов.

Хочу сделать чтоб при введении последовательности букв из списка ниже скрывались города, не содержащие введенную последовательность.

Дайте наводку куда копать

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос некорректный, но посмотреть пример для jquery можно вот тут, https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#maxheight

Впрочем, это не самый оптимальный вариант, но т.к. код Вы не привели, думаю, что подобная наводка уже может чем-то помочь.